# Directing low output sound frequencies to aux and playing the high ones on the pc's speakers

Tags: audio

My very old sound system broke down recently and only the subwoofer works. While working on a replacement, I was wondering if there's a way to send only the lower frequencies through the headphone jack and play the higher ones in my pc's (thinkpad x240 with Pop!Os) speakers